# How to read arrays from JSON file?

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, cursor

I am trying to read data from JSON. I add Firebase to my Android application and everyhing works fine, but i don't understand how to read array fields.

For example, I need to get `"correctAnswers":["Var1","Var4"]` field, but can't google answer how to do it.

Please explain.
Thank you.

part of my JSON file

```
 {
    "answA" : "Var1",
    "answB" : "Var2",
    "answC" : "Var3",
    "answD" : "Var4",
    "categoryId" : 1,
    "correctAnswers":["Var1","Var4"],
    "id" : 104,
  }
```

I get the cursor

```
Cursor cursor = sqlLiteDataBaseInstance.rawQuery(String.format("SELECT * FROM Question WHERE CategoryID = %d ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 30", category), null);
```

and can read `answA, answB, answC, answD`  using

`cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(String columnName))` and

`categoryId, id using cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(String columnName))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

```
  private void readJson() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\n" +
                    "\t\"answA\": \"Var1\",\n" +
                    "\t\"answB\": \"Var2\",\n" +
                    "\t\"answC\": \"Var3\",\n" +
                    "\t\"answD\": \"Var4\",\n" +
                    "\t\"categoryId\": 1,\n" +
                    "\t\"correctAnswers\": [\"Var1\", \"Var4\"],\n" +
                    "\t\"id\": 104\n" +
                    "}");

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("correctAnswers");
            Log.e("Array Size is ", jsonArray.length() + "");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                Log.e("Array Values", jsonArray.getString(i) + "");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```